Minimal description of polyhedral cone and matrix rank
Suppose there is a polyhedral cone defined by
$P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \pmb A x \leq \pmb 0\}$.
The matrix $\pmb A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $n>m$ potentially contains redundant inequalities.
Is there a relation between the number of irredundant inequalities and the rank of the matrix $\pmb A$? Especially, if $\bar{\pmb A} \in \mathbb{R}^{s\times m}$ is the minimal (redundancy free) description of $P$, does $s = \mathrm{rank}(\pmb A)$ hold?

No: $P = {0} = {x: Ax \le0}$ with $A = (-1,1)^T$, $rank(A)=1$, but $s=2$.

No. Consider for instance
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Observe that the rank of $A$ is $1$ but there are no redundant inequalities.
If you removed one inequality, would would get a half-space:
$$
\{x : x_1 + x_2 \le 0\}\text{ or } \{x : x_1 + x_2 \ge 0\}
$$
However,
$$
\begin{aligned}
P 
&= \{x : Ax \le 0\}\\
&= \{x : x_1 + x_2 \le 0 \text{ and } x_1 + x_2 \ge 0\}\\
&= \{x : x_1+x_2 = 0\}
\end{aligned}
$$
so $P$ is just a line.
Note: this is basically the same example as the comment, but with an additional column.

Thanks a lot for the answer!
One more question though: What if we were to constrain $\pmb A$ to be $\in \mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}$?
(Should be the same as requiring that hidden equalities are forbidden, right?)

@stepze Consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
3& 2& 1\
1&2&3\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix},.
$$
Looking at this quickly, the matrix has rank $2$ but none of the inequalities are redundant.
